# Why react does not show updated value even if state changes?

Tags: reactjs, variables, react-bootstrap, setstate

I am just experimenting with ReactJS and came to an issue. I just want to update a variable according to the value of BootstrapSwitchButton. After some time of debugging, I came to a conclusion that variable is updating as needed but is not being displayed inside react rendering part but shows updated value from a function.
My code is:

```
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);
  let btnValue;
  
  function changeValue(value)
  {
    console.log("Value: " + value)
    btnValue = value;
    setState(value); 
    console.log("Button Value at function: " + btnValue)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BootstrapSwitchButton checked={true} onlabel="On" offlabel="Off" width={100} onChange={changeValue}/>
    {console.log("Button Value: " + btnValue)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**I just want to know that what's happening here? Why react does not show updated value even if state changes?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use local variables in a component context since they are not covered by state lifecycle. React does not know of this variable and hence does not "track" it. Instead of `btnValue`, use your `state`, since then react will take care of any actions associated with changes in your component. You can read more about that in the react [state and lifecycle page](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

```js
function changeValue(value)
  {
    console.log("Value: " + value)
    setState(value); 
    console.log("Button Value at function: " + value)
  }
return (
    <div className="App">
      <BootstrapSwitchButton checked={true} onlabel="On" offlabel="Off" width={100} onChange={changeValue}/>
    {console.log("Button Value: " + state)}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Yup! React renders are async so value in that thread doesnt get updated. Thanks. :)

Comment: I think this has less to do with state updates being async but rerendering triggering only on state updates at all. Changing `btnValue` to another value does not trigger any updates regarding the component lifecycle, i.e. no rerendering.